# Cypher : load csv with multiple null based conditioning(neo4j)

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am new to the cypher query era.

I am trying to load csv and creating the relation between two nodes based on match.
Match between two need is depend on csv data, csv has assignment data like,

```
Id,EmployeeId,DepartmentId,AppId,Name
11, 222, ,2, abc
12, , 433, pqr
13, , , xyz
```

I have to build relation between `Application` Node and `Employee` Node.
So my query is like,

```
    LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///assignment.csv' as ass 
    
    MATCH(c:Application),(e:Employee)
    WHERE
    c.appId = ass.AppId
    AND 

    e.employeeId= ass.employeeId AND e.departmentId= ass.departmentId // line 6
    // here in line 6, condition should be based on null values of employeeId and departmentId

    MERGE (e)-[r: OWNS
    {assignment_id: ass.ID}]->(c)
```

For some assignments employeeId can be null so in this case line 6 condition like

```
e.departmentId= ass.departmentId
```

For some assignments departmentId can be null so in this case line 6 condition like

```
e.employeeId= ass.employeeId
```

For some cases both employeeId and departmentId can be null so that case, there should be any condtion or can be `true=true`

I tried for ForEach(), UNWIND but got the syntax error.
I tried with CASE WHEN conditioning but got the syntax error.

Comment: Do you have some employee nodes where the departmentId or employeeId is null? I wonder if it makes sense to refactor your data model to create Department nodes. You might experiment with the coalesce() function. e.g. coalesce(e.employeeId, "None") = coalesce(ass.employeeId, "None")

Comment: What is expected in case of nulls? The expected output

Comment: Yes, It worked. As suggested by @NathanSmith Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here are three options;

1. create the CSV omitting the rows with null values.
2. create the nodes and then add (using set) the properties, the latter skipping nodes without the property.
3. use a case statement to set default values for nulls. An example of the query from one of my projects

   merge (f:DNA_Match{fullname:trim(toString(case when line.First_Name is null then '' else line.First_Name end + case when line.Middle_Name is null then '' else ' ' + line.Middle_Name end + case when line.Last_Name is null then '' else ' ' + line.Last_Name end))}) set f.first_name=toString(case when line.First_Name is null then '' else line.First_Name end), f.middle_name=toString(case when line.Middle_Name is null then '' else line.Middle_Name end), f.surname=trim(toString(case when line.Last_Name is null then '' else line.Last_Name end))